# netlogo, how to collect types of info to complete an array

Tags: arrays, netlogo

I have seen similar questions for Javascript, but not NetLogo.

I have a bunch of turtles moving around the screen, running into each other and exchanging information. I am trying to set up an array that represents different types of information that need to be collected (ie: slot one may represent a date, slot two may represent a country, slot three may represent an organization) as the turtles run into other turtles and see if turtleA has info that TurtleB needs to complete his collection.

Right now I have it set up so each piece of information is identical, and all we're checking is whether you have enough pieces to be done. I'm hoping to make it more like a bingo card getting checked off, if that makes sense:

```
to move-turtles
ask Implementers [
   [ifelse any? Other Turtles-here [have-info] [change-location];; if anyone     else is here, ask if they have info, otherwise, move. 
]
end

to have-info
ifelse any? turtles-here with [holdinfo > 0] [do-i-have-enough-info] [change-location]
end

to do-i-have-enough-info
ask Implementers [
ifelse holdinfo >= taskcomplexity [move-to one-of (patch-set patch 17 20 patch -17 -20 patch 17 -20 patch -17 20) set done 1 stop] [change-location];; move to   end
]
ask OtherImplementers [
ifelse holdinfo >= tcomplexity [move-to one-of (patch-set patch 17 20 patch -17 -20 patch 17 -20 patch -17 20) set done 1 stop][change-location]];; move to end
ask IMdeployed [change-location];; keep moving

end
```

Update:
I've now tried assigning random array-lengths to my different breeds -

```
ask Implementers [set infoarray array:from-list n-values taskcomplexity [0]]
```

Now I'm trying to find a way to set the array item values as all 0, until the Implementer runs into someone who already has a value for a particular item in the array, at which point the item value will switch to 1, until eventually each implementer has a full array of 1s.

Any ideas?